# Why cell is display overflow the table view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have fix make the cell to cliptobounds in the table view and also assign constraints to fix the table position and height.

Below are some parts of my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    if hiddenRow.contains(indexPath.row) || hiddenRow2.contains(indexPath.row){
        rowHeight.append(300)
        return 300 //Expanded
    }
    else{
        rowHeight.append(120)
        return 120 //Not Expanded
    }
    
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "med_reusable_cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MedListTableViewCell
    
    cell.backgroundColor = TRANSPARENT
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = DEFAULT_CORNER_RADIUS
    
    active_table_height.constant = self.view.frame.size.height * 11/36
    expired_table_height.constant = self.view.frame.size.height * 11/36
```

[cell overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWvpz.png)

The different between my code and others are

1. This is an expendable view cell which the height will be change based whether the cell is expended
2. I use a reusable cell for two tables.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a header to each cell, then when you'll click it, reload the table view with the opened cell look at this example :

**DataModel** :

```
struct  DataItem {
    var isExpand: Bool
    var title: String
    var value:String
    
    
    init(isExpand:Bool = false, title:String, value:String) {

        self.isExpand = isExpand
        self.title = title
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

**Custom Header** witch will listen to events :

```
protocol CustomHeaderViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func headerViewTap(_ section: Int)
}

class CustomHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    weak var delegate: CustomHeaderViewDelegate?
    var sectionNumber: Int?
            
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomHeaderView.tableViewSectionTapped(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func tableViewSectionTapped(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let sectionNumber =  sectionNumber{
            delegate?.headerViewTap(sectionNumber)
        }
    }
}
```

**TableView and Custom Header delegates**

```
extension ViewController :  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    //The number of sections fits the number of cells, the current list is an array of DataObject, holding a title and a content.
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.currentList.count
    }
    //Each section(group of cells) contains one row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    
    //update heights for row if the header has been taped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let isExpanded = self.currentList[indexPath.section].isExpand
        if isExpanded {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
        return 0
    }
    //update the estimatedHeightForRowAt if the hader has been taped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let isExpanded = self.currentList[indexPath.section].isExpand
        if isExpanded{
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    //returns a custom header
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "Header") as! CustomHeaderView
        return headerView
    }
}

extension ViewController : CustomeHeaderViewDelegate{
    func headerViewTap(_ section: Int) {
        selectedItem = self.currentList[section]
        let output = self.currentList.map({ (item:DataItem) -> DataItem in
            var result = item
            if result.title == self.selectedItem?.title{
                result.isExpand = !result.isExpand
            }
            return result
        })
        self.currentList = output
        self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: section), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```